# Generic sets in ZFC

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm reading Shelah's book "Proper and Improper Forcing" (the first two chapters were recommended for learning the basics of forcing)

Given a quasi-order $P$ we say that $\mathcal{I}$ is a *dense* subset of $P$  if
$$(\forall p \in P) (\exists q \in \mathcal{I}) (p\le q)$$

We say that it is open if for any $p,q \in P$ we have that $p \in \mathcal{I} \wedge p\le q$ then $q \in \mathcal{I}$

$G$ is called *directed* if every two elements in $G$ has an upper bound in $G$.

$G$ is called *downward closed* if for every $p \in G$ and $q\in P$ if $q \le p$ then $q \in G$

A subset $G$ of $P$ is called *generic* over $V$ if it is directed, downward closed and for any dense and open subset of $P$ that is in $V$, the intersection with $G$ is non-empty.

Now they give proof that if $P$ has no trivial branches then a generic set cannot exist in the universe, saying that if $G \in V$ then $P\backslash G \in V$ and it is dense and open, how come? I can't figure that out.

Comment: Can you remind me what trivial branch is, please?

Comment: Nevermind - I found it:  above any element, there are two elements with no common upper bound.  (My edit timer ran out as I was typing this!)

Comment: Also, in Shelah's book, it seems that "directed" has a different meaning:  that any two elements have a common upperbound (see page 3, at least on the projecteuclid version)  (*again* the edit timer ran out as I was typing this!).  If the mods can (and would like to) combine all these into a single comment, I'd be more than happy with that.)

Comment: I was always taught that a directed set is a set that every two elements has an upper bound.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about ;) I'll fix that. (man that comments edit timer is really short)

Comment: If you'd like, I can delete all my comments and edit the first paragraph of my answer, now that you've corrected the definition of directed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use the def of "directed" that I found in Shelah's [book](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Proper-and-Improper-Forcing/toc/pl/1235419814)<sup>1</sup>:  A set $G$ is directed if it is downward closed (if $p$ in G and if $q\leq p$ then $q\in G$) **and** every two memebers of $G$ have a common upperbound in $G$.

To see that $P-G$ is open is not too hard:  Let $p\in P-G$ and suppose $q\in G$ with $p\leq q$.  If $q$ were in $G$, then since $G$ is downwardly closed, we'd have $p\in G$, but that contradicts $p\in P-G$.  Thus, $q\notin G$ so $q\in P-G$.

Now, why is $P-G$ dense?  Well, let $p\in P$.  We want to find a $q\in P-G$ with $p\leq q$.  Since there are no trivial branches, we know that above $p$ and are two points $r$ and $s$ with no common upperbound.  Since $G$ is directed, $r$ and $s$ cannot both be in $G$.  Hence, say, $r\notin G$.  Then $r\in P-G$, so we're done.

<sup>1</sup>I'm using chapter 1 and finding the definition on page 3 of the .pdf.

Comment: Just one minor technicality which I think I got but not really sure - why is $P\backslash G \in V$ if $G \in V$?

Comment: Since $V$ is a model of $ZFC$, it satisfies the axiom of comprehension.  That's the axiom (schema) which allows you to form sets of the form $\{x\in A| \phi(x)\}$, where $\phi$ is some first order formula (with parameters).

In this case, $P-G = \{p\in P | p\notin G\}$ which uses the parameter $G$.

Comment: Just what I thought myself. I'm all so new to the idea of taking models of ZFC and it's all very confusing.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my link Grigory!