# Generic filters in the ground model (forcing)

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

In his book *Set Theory* (second edition), page 203, Thomas Jech writes

> **Lemma 14.4** Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be a countable model of ZFC and $P$ be a partially ordered set. If $p\in P$, there exists a generic filter on $P$.

Then, the following exercise is given:

> **Exercise** Let $\mathfrak{M}$ as above. Let $P\in M$ be a partially ordered set with no atom (for every $p\in P$, then there exist $q,r\in P$ such that $q,r\le p$ and
>   $q,r$ are incompatible). If $G\subset P$ is generic over $\mathfrak{M}$,
>   then $G\not\in \mathfrak{M}$.

The short proof of Lemma 14.4 is given [here](http://books.google.ch/books?id=WTAl997XDb4C&lpg=PA281&dq=jech%20set%20theory%20exercise%2016.6&hl=fr&pg=PA203#v=onepage&q=jech%20set%20theory%20exercise%2016.6&f=false):

[image]

According to the exercise, the filter $G$ constructed in this proof must fail to belong to $\mathfrak{M}$ in some cases. But why ? Since $P\in \mathfrak{M}$ it seems that $G\in \mathfrak{M}$ using comprehension, doesn't it ?

Comment: Related, and possibly a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275/generic-sets-in-zfc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $G$ belongs to $\mathfrak{M}$, then so does $P \setminus G$.  Since $P$ has no atoms, it is easy to show that $P \setminus G$ is dense in $P$, and therefore $G \cap ( P \setminus G ) \neq \emptyset$ by genericity, which is absurd!

The point is that in the proof of Lemma 14.4 you enumerated the dense subsets of $P$ which belong to $\mathfrak{M}$, and this enumeration will generally take place *outside* of $\mathfrak{M}$, and in the "real world".  From this there is no reason to expect that the sequence of conditions of $P$ you base your generic set $G$ on belongs to $\mathfrak{M}$, and therefore there is little reason to expect that the generic set itself belongs to $\mathfrak{M}$.  In fact, the exercise makes it clear that under fairly mild (and *very* common) assumptions the generic set will provably *not* belong to $\mathfrak{M}$.

Answer (score 2):

Comprehension says (eliding some details) that $\{x\in A | \varphi(x)\}$ exists in $\mathfrak{M}$ for any formula $\phi$ (with parameters); presumably you intend $A$ here to be $P$.  But there is not generally going to be any such formula $\varphi$ to define a generic filter $G$, so comprehension won't tell you that such a $G \in \mathfrak{M}$.

Comment: Here, $G$ would be the union of the $G_n=\{x\in P : x\ge p_n\}$. What is the problem with the formula $\varphi$="$x\ge p_n$" ?

Comment: Assuming that by $p_n$ you mean elements of $P$, wouldn't that just be all of $P$, and not a filter on $P$?

Comment: I mean the $p_n$ as defined in the linked proof. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: The linked page just tells me I can't view the page...

Comment: I added a screenshot to the post :)

Comment: The set of all $p_n$ may not be in $\mathfrak{M}$ (in fact, it isn't in general).

Comment: Oh, that's right. We have $P\in\mathfrak{M}$, but the subset $\{p_n\}$ might not belong to $\mathfrak{M}$ itself. Thank you!